# Quantum mechanics on operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, observables

If any operator is commute with Hamilton then they are labelled such a way that the energy eigenstate are equal and we also know it is a constant of motion. I don't related constant of motion with above theory. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space and $H$ the Hamiltonian of a quantum system: one can show (Ehrenfest theorem) that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle A \rangle = \frac{1}{i\hbar}\langle [A, H] \rangle + \langle \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \rangle
$$
where $\langle A \rangle$ denotes the expectation value onto a generic state $|\psi\rangle$. Therefore unless the operator explicitly depends on time, it is a constant of motion as long as it commutes with the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Can you explain the explicitly dependence by an example.

Comment: What in particular don't you understand?

Comment: The explicitly dependence of operator on time

Comment: Well, take any function explicitly depending on time (this has nothing to do with quantum mechanics: if the problems are what a partial derivate is then it is another question).